# Running preview/preprod Cardano-node on windows

Tags: cardano-node

Im trying to run preprod node .
steps i followed :

1- downloaded these files : https://book.world.dev.cardano.org/environments/preprod/

2- run this :
cardano-node.exe run --topology ./configuration/cardano/topology.json --database-path ./db --port 3001 --config ./configuration/cardano/config.json --socket-path .\pipe\cardano-node and

but i get this error : [image]

doesnt happen with mainnet or old dead testnet .... any idea ?

Answer (score 1):

it looks like your socket-path and the wrong facing slashes should be ./pipe/cardano-node.

Also not sure how you built your node but typically the socket path is in the DB folder so in your case ./db and typically socket is ./db/socket