# Unable to run cardano-node on Preview and Pre-Production Testnet

Tags: cardano-node, testnet

System Info: macOS Monterey Version 12.6. with an M1 Chip.

I'm using cardano-node 1.35.3 that is installed with the Daedalus Mainnet wallet by appending the following in my .zshrc file:

```
export PATH="/Applications/Daedalus Mainnet.app/Contents/MacOS:$PATH"
```

I followed this guide to run `cardano-node`: https://developers.cardano.org/docs/get-started/running-cardano/

I get the configuration files from here: https://book.world.dev.cardano.org/environments.html

As in the guide above, my directory structure looks like this:

```
$HOME/cardano/
├── db
├── alonzo-genesis.json
├── byron-genesis.json
├── config.json
├── shelley-genesis.json
└── topology.json
1 directory, 5 files
```

In this directory, I run the following command:

```
cardano-node run \
  --topology topology.json \
  --database-path db \
  --socket-path db/node.socket \
  --host-addr 127.0.0.1 \
  --port 1337 \
  --config config.json
```

When I use the configuration files for mainnet and the old testnet, the command works as expected and the node is syncing because I see output like this:

```
Chain extended, new tip: b4624d1ad9fa00eaf81b57fa0561f24593d11adca70b45ee967484c8d5c26efa at slot 27173
```

However, when using the configuration files for the preview and pre-production testnet, I get the following output/error which repeats itself and the node does not sync. How can I solve this?

```
[student-:cardano.node.PeerSelection:Info:52] [2022-10-07 14:09:06.10 UTC] TraceGovernorWakeup
[student-:cardano.node.PeerSelection:Info:52] [2022-10-07 14:09:06.10 UTC] TracePromoteColdPeers 50 0 (fromList [3.72.231.105:30002])
[student-:cardano.node.ConnectionManager:Info:68] [2022-10-07 14:09:06.10 UTC] TrConnectionManagerCounters (ConnectionManagerCounters {fullDuplexConns = 0, duplexConns = 0, unidirectionalConns = 0, inboundConns = 0, outboundConns = 0})
[student-:cardano.node.ConnectionManager:Info:68] [2022-10-07 14:09:06.10 UTC] TrConnectError (Just 127.0.0.1:3001) 3.72.231.105:30002 Network.Socket.connect: <socket: 29>: unsupported operation (Can't assign requested address)
[student-:cardano.node.ConnectionManager:Info:68] [2022-10-07 14:09:06.10 UTC] TrConnectionManagerCounters (ConnectionManagerCounters {fullDuplexConns = 0, duplexConns = 0, unidirectionalConns = 0, inboundConns = 0, outboundConns = 0})
[student-:cardano.node.PeerSelection:Info:52] [2022-10-07 14:09:06.10 UTC] TracePromoteColdFailed 50 0 3.72.231.105:30002 41.140901877674s Network.Socket.connect: <socket: 29>: unsupported operation (Can't assign requested address)
[student-:cardano.node.PeerSelection:Info:52] [2022-10-07 14:09:29.81 UTC] TraceGovernorWakeup
[student-:cardano.node.PeerSelection:Info:52] [2022-10-07 14:09:29.81 UTC] TracePublicRootsRequest 100 1
[student-:cardano.node.LedgerPeers:Info:50] [2022-10-07 14:09:29.81 UTC] [String "FetchingNewLedgerState",Number 0.0]
[student-:cardano.node.LedgerPeers:Info:50] [2022-10-07 14:09:29.82 UTC] [String "FallingBackToBootstrapPeers"]
[student-:cardano.node.LedgerPeers:Info:50] [2022-10-07 14:09:29.82 UTC] [String "UseLedgerAfter",Number 322000.0]
[student-:cardano.node.PublicRootPeers:Info:69] [2022-10-07 14:09:29.82 UTC] TracePublicRootRelayAccessPoint [RelayAccessDomain "preview-node.world.dev.cardano.org" 30002]
[student-:cardano.node.PublicRootPeers:Info:69] [2022-10-07 14:09:29.82 UTC] TracePublicRootRelayAccessPoint [RelayAccessDomain "preview-node.world.dev.cardano.org" 30002]
[student-:cardano.node.PublicRootPeers:Info:69] [2022-10-07 14:09:29.85 UTC] TracePublicRootResult "preview-node.world.dev.cardano.org" [(3.72.231.105,60)]
[student-:cardano.node.PeerSelection:Info:52] [2022-10-07 14:09:29.85 UTC] TracePublicRootsResults (fromList []) 1 2s
```

Full output here: https://gist.github.com/samuelpullely/60223a98066dd5f72c597a681021c2a3

Similar (unresolved) questions:

1. [Cardano-Node Preview Testnet PeerSelection Error](https://cardano.stackexchange.com/questions/9162/cardano-node-preview-testnet-peerselection-error) (Ubuntu 22.04 Docker container)
2. [Running preview/preprod Cardano-node on windows](https://cardano.stackexchange.com/questions/9056/running-preview-preprod-cardano-node-on-windows) (Windows)

It seems like this issue does not only appear on macOS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When I copied and pasted text, I faced the similar problem. May be formatting matters. Try getting raw files directly from github like:

```
curl -O -J https://raw.githubusercontent.com/input-output-hk/cardano-world/master/docs/environments/preprod/alonzo-genesis.json
```

Change "/preprod/" to "/preview/" and "alonzo-genesis.json" to other names, to fit your needs.

Also in my case, I have to change host-addr to 0.0.0.0 like:

```
--host-addr 0.0.0.0 \
```

Lastly, make sure the database in db folder is NOT from the mainnet/testnet/different net. To be super-safe, just empty the db folder.

Comment: Thanks a lot, changing the host-addr worked